# Magento: Allow users to enter message on cart which is added to order

Tags: php, magento

I was wondering if it was possible to allow users on the shopping cart to enter a message that will be added to the order.  A screenshot below shows what I mean:

http://i46.tinypic.com/3523rll.jpg

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @

- [Magento. Add order comment attribute to order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152186/magento-add-order-comment-attribute-to-order)
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-order-comment.html
- http://www.brimllc.com/2010/07/magento-adding-custom-shipping-comments-at-checkout/